# scrapy Request url and Response url are different

Tags: python, scrapy

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from urllib.parse import unquote, quote

class md3(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "md3"
    allowed_domains = ["mawdoo3.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://mawdoo3.com"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for listing in response.css("ul.category-items > li"):
            lister = {}
            namelist = listing.css("a::text").extract_first()

            for i in range(1, 8):
                listurl = "https://mawdoo3.com/index.php?action=ajax&rs=JsonCategories&rsargs[]="+str(i)+"&rsargs[]="+str(namelist.replace(" ", "_"))

                lister['listurl'] = listurl
                yield scrapy.Request(url=listurl, callback=self.parseresponse, meta={"lister": lister})

    def parseresponse(self, response):
        response.meta.get("lister")['responseurl'] = unquote(response.url)

        yield response.meta.get("lister")
```

this spider is supposed to get data from a link like

```
https://mawdoo3.com/index.php?action=ajax&rs=JsonCategories&rsargs[]=1&rsargs[]=منوعات_عن_الطبيعة
```

but in the **lister** value i get

```
[
  {
    "listurl" = "https://mawdoo3.com/index.php?action=ajax&rs=JsonCategories&rsargs[]=2&rsargs[]=منوعات_عن_الطبيعة",
    "responseurl" = "https://mawdoo3.com/index.php?action=ajax&rs=JsonCategories&rsargs[]=1&rsargs[]=%D8%B2%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%B9%D8%A9_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AE%D8%B6%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%AA_%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%81%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%83%D9%87"
  }
]
```

if decoded the **rsargs[1]** it becomes a total different name from **listurl** and **rsargs[0]** is a different number and if repeated it the **responseurl** is always random and more random if increased the **range(1, 3)**

what is problem with spider?

---

what i want is to get the same results in **listurl** and **responseurl** because i sent the **listurl** in a call for function `def parseresponse` but the **responseurl** which is supposed ot be **listurl** is totally different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
>>> from urllib.parse import unquote                                                                                                                                           
>>> response.url                                                                                                                                                               
'https://mawdoo3.com/index.php?action=ajax&rs=JsonCategories&rsargs[]=1&rsargs[]=%D8%A3%D8%B7%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%82_%D8%B1%D8%A6%D9%8A%D8%B3%D9%8A%D8%A9'
>>> unquote(response.url)                                                                                                                                                      
'https://mawdoo3.com/index.php?action=ajax&rs=JsonCategories&rsargs[]=1&rsargs[]=أطباق_رئيسية'
```

---

**EDIT**

I'm sorry, I thought you were complaining about the encoding, but the real question was about the numbers, right?

The problem is that `lister = {}` is outside the inner for loop. Thus, you're passing the same object reference to the callbacks but you keep updating it. A quick fix would be:

```py
for i in range(1, 8):
    listurl = "https://mawdoo3.com/index.php?action=ajax&rs=JsonCategories&rsargs[]="+str(i)+"&rsargs[]="+str(namelist.replace(" ", "_"))

    lister{}
    lister['listurl'] = listurl
    yield scrapy.Request(url=listurl, callback=self.parseresponse, meta={"lister": lister})
```

Comment: i tried quote and unquote but the `rsargs[0]` numbers are still different in the json, added the full code, feel free to test it.

Comment: the numbers are different check first line numbers [`rsargs[]=7`,`rsargs[]=1`] or any other numbers